# validando somente .com.br regex

Tags: c++, regex, email

Pessoal estava modificando uma regex para validar somente domínios específicos que termine com yahoo.com.br, terra.com.br, bol.com.br, hotmail.com.br. Então gmail.com, ou provedor.net.br seriam inválidos.

Então fiz a regex abaixo:

```
const std::regex pattern("([a-zA-Z0-9._]+@[hotmail|terra|yahoo|bol]+(?:[.][com]{2,4})?(?:[.][br]{1,2})?)");
```

Mas está validando também email que termine somente com `.com` ou se eu digitar: `usuario@yahoo.com` ele valida e não poderia validar.

Já tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```
const std::regex pattern("([a-zA-Z0-9._]+@(?:[hotmail.com.br|terra.com.br|yahoo.com.br|bol.com.br]{2,4})?)");
```

Mas aí ele retorna tudo inválido. Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não está funcionando pois, da primeira forma, você está colocando um **?** no br. Isso, no regex, quer dizer que o valor é opcional.

A segunda forma, quando você informa **{2,4}**, você quer dizer para o software pegar apenas os dados entre 2 e 4 caracteres, por isso ele só pega metade do valor e consequentemente valida.

Outro problema é que você está utilizando o **com**, **br** e os provedores, dentro dos colchetes. Isso faz com que o código pegue informações que possuem as mesmas letras, não necessariamente a palavra. Ex: Ele valida valores como *hootmail*, *hhhooottmmmaaiill*, etc. O ideal nesse caso, é utiliza parentes.

Para seu caso, o regex abaixo deve funcionar.
`([a-zA-Z0-9._]+@(?:hotmail|terra|yahoo|bol)\.(?:com\.br))`

[**Regex**](https://regex101.com/r/SUKycG/2)

[**Regex Debugger**](https://regex101.com/r/SUKycG/2/debugger)

[**Regex Tests**](https://regex101.com/r/SUKycG/2/tests)

Comment: muito bom agora com base nesta vou escrever outra pra validar dominios .net.org.br